# Getting object null exception while unit testing post method in webapi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tdd, moq, asp.net-web-api

**MoviesController**

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a New Movie in Movie Data Source
/// </summary>
/// <param name="movie">Movie</param>
/// <returns>HttpResponseMessage</returns>
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Movie movie)
{
    try
    {
        int i = repository.InsertMovie(movie);
        var response = Request.CreateResponse<Movie>(HttpStatusCode.Created, movie);
        **string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApiWithMovieId", new { movieId = i });**
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
        return response;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

**WebApiConfig**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultApiWithMovieId",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{movieId}",
               defaults: new { movieId = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

**Test Method**

```
[TestMethod]
public void Post_Movie_Returns_StatusCode_Created()
{

    MoviesController controller = new MoviesController(movieRepository.Object);
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost/api/movies");
    var route = config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithMovieId", "api/{controller}/{movieId}");
    var routeData = new HttpRouteData(route, new HttpRouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "movies" } });
    //var controller = new ProductsController(repo);
    controller.ControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext(config, routeData, request);
    controller.Request = request;
    controller.Request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = config;
    Movie movie = new Movie() { Title = "SpiderMan", ReleaseYear = 09, Rating = 4, MovieId = 81, Genre = "Romance", Classification = "Good", Cast = { } };
    movieRepository.Setup(x => x.InsertMovie(It.IsAny<Movie>())).Returns(movie.MovieId);
    var result = controller.Post(movie);
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.Created, result.StatusCode);

}
```

While executing above test case,In Controller post method,at the highlighted  line i am getting exeception
*Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending the `routeData` into the request. Add this line:

```
controller.Request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpRouteDataKey] = routeData;
```